# PHP find US state code in string

Tags: php, regex

I have strings that are formatted as below:

"Houston, TX" - str1 
"Chicago, IL" - str2 
"Seattle, WA" - str3

i want to extract "TX", "IL", "WA" when given each of the above str1/str2/str3, *if* a state code exists in string (i.e. 2 upper case letters at end of string) using PHP & regex.. any pointers.. i am unable to reliably extract this info from all the strings given to my method.

Comment: For regex try this handy tool: http://txt2re.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use regular expressions for this. Assuming the state code can only appear at the very end of a string, you can use this small function:

```
/**
 * Extracts the US state code from a string and returns it, otherwise
 * returns false.
 *
 * "Houston, TX" - returns "TX"
 * "TX, Houston" - returns false
 *
 * @return string|boolean
 */
function getStateCode($string)
{
    // I'm not familiar with all the state codes, you
    // should add them yourself.
    $codes = array('TX', 'IL', 'WA');

    $code = strtoupper(substr($string, -2));

    if(in_array($code, $codes))
    {
        return $code;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `/, [A-Z]{2}$/` (remove the comma if it's not important).

Comment: Or use `/, ([A-Z]{2})$/` and grab the group instead of the whole match.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$stateCode=trim(end(array_filter(explode(',',$string))));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
substr($string, -2); // returns the last 2 characters
```